# update date if it is one day late

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[image]

The user (user_id) has data enter in different time period. The data is consider same set if the date is one day later. Mainly I want to change the date in 3rd row equal to 2nd row.

```
UPDATE #temp
SET CUR_VALUE_DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CUR_VALUE_DATETIME)
WHERE CUR_VALUE_DATETIME <= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CUR_VALUE_DATETIME)
```

The above approach I tried return nothing.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause will never be true since you are trying to match cur_value_datetime with 1 day less than the same value. Basically you are updating records where 1/2/2015 = 1/1/2015. I assume cur_value_datetime is the same as CUR_VALUE_DATETIME?

Comment: Yes.cur_value_datetime is same as CUR_VALUE_DATETIME. I do noticed where clause will never be true, but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do with this particular example, you will need to compare each date with any date that happens to be one greater.  You can do this with a self join.

```
    update t1
    set t1.curr_value_datetime = t2.curr_value_datetime
    from #temp t1
       join #temp t2
          on t1.curr_value_datetime - 1 = t2.curr_value_datetime
```

However, since you mention user_id, you will want to tweak this to take user_id into account.  Otherwise you will run into problems.